# Change the Form Region Button Icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin

How do I go about changing the ribbon button icon that links to a specific form region in an outlook add in? It currently just looks like a folder icon and has the name of our app. (Visual Studio 2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define Form Region icons in the Properties window for your FormRegion item:

[image]

Also see:

- [Guidelines for Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386176.aspx#UsingOptimal)
- [FormRegionManifestIcons Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.outlook.formregionmanifesticons.aspx)